# Convertir de .py a .exe

Tags: python

Probé con distintas herramientas y al realizarlo, mi exe no hace nada, agradecería su ayuda, adjunto el código de mi script (cabe mencionar que introduje el archivo rsc que se necesita para realizar dicho proceso de creación del nuevo rsc)

```
import os
import sys  # Importa el módulo sys

# Obtener la ruta del directorio actual
current_directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

# Buscar un archivo con extensión .rsc en el directorio actual
rsc_files = [f for f in os.listdir(current_directory) if f.endswith('.rsc')]

if len(rsc_files) == 0:
    # No se encontraron archivos con la extensión .rsc en este directorio.
    sys.exit()

# Seleccionar el primer archivo .rsc encontrado en el directorio
file_path = os.path.join(current_directory, rsc_files[0])

# Lee el archivo y guarda los datos en una lista
with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()

# Elimina los símbolos "\" y une las líneas correspondientes
cleaned_lines = []
current_line = ''
for line in lines:
    line = line.strip()  # Elimina espacios en blanco al inicio y final de cada línea
    current_line += line.replace('\\', '')  # Elimina el símbolo "\" y concatena las líneas
    if not line.endswith('\\'):
        cleaned_lines.append(current_line)  # Agrega la línea completa a la lista si no termina con "\"
        current_line = ''  # Reinicia la línea actual

# Escribe los datos limpios en un nuevo archivo
output_file_path = os.path.join(current_directory, 'datos_limpios.rsc')
with open(output_file_path, 'w') as clean_file:
    for line in cleaned_lines:
        clean_file.write(line + '\n')
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Yo no se python, pero seria conveniente que agregaras salidas por consola a modo de log, para saber donde es que tu programa esta fallando...

Comment: Evidentemente, cuando conviertes el script en un ejecutable, ya no hay script y el atributo `__file__` no contiene nada. Se podría usar `sys.executable`, pero depende de qué herramienta uses para crear el ejecutable. Si usas pyinstaller, revisa la documentación: https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/runtime-information.html#using-file